# How to make child div scrollable on page resize? css

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rayabu1234/tyccuqnp/)

I spent some time on this, but cannot resolve this CSS issue. I have 4 nested `div`s. The inner most child `div`, holds a table of rows.

HTML structure:

```
<div class="moduleContentContainer">
<div id="dash-board-container">
    <div class="dash-board-item">
        <div>pENDING QUOTES</div>
        <div class=".quote_list_container">
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr><th>Names</th></tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr><td>ssss</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>ssss</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>ssss</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>ssss</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>ssss</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>ssss</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>ssss</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>ssggggss</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>ssggggss</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>ssggggss</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>ssggggss</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>ssggggss</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>ssggggss</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>ssggggss</td></tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

(1) I want the dash_Board_Item Div to have its height based on the size of its content(the content in the .quote_list_container div"). So if there is one row, in the table, dash-board-item `div` should be small in height and taller otherwise, depending on content.

(2) When the window resize, display a scroll bar on the .quote_list_container `div` when required.

Answer (score 0):

1) Remove the default margin from the body element with `body { margin:0; }`

2) Set height:100% to parent divs of table, body and html

3) Since you only want the scrollbar on the quote_list_container div, you need to know the height of the title, then you can use calc to set the quote_list_container div with max-height:100% minus the height of the title

4) You have what looks like a typo in your markup on the quote_list_container div you named the class witha preceding dot. You probably didn't mean that.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/tyccuqnp/2/)**

```css
body {
    margin:0;
}
html, body, .moduleContentContainer {
    height: 100%;
}
.title {
    height: 30px;
}
#dash-board-container {
    position: absolute;
    height: 90%;
}
.dash-board-item {
    height: 100%;
    margin-right: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    border-style: solid;
    max-width: 700px;
    min-width: 300px;
    border-color: #999999;
    border-width: 1px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    position: relative;
}
.quote_list_container {
    max-height: calc(100% - 30px);
    overflow: auto;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="moduleContentContainer">
    <div id="dash-board-container">
        <div class="dash-board-item">
            <div class="title">pENDING QUOTES</div>
            <div class="quote_list_container">
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Names</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>ssss</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>ssss</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>ssss</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>ssss</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>ssss</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>ssss</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>ssss</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>ssggggss</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>ssggggss</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>ssggggss</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>ssggggss</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>ssggggss</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>ssggggss</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>ssggggss</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>ssggggss</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>ssggggss</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>ssggggss</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>ssggggss</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>ssggggss</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>ssggggss</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>ssggggss</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>ssggggss</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>ssggggss</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <table>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        
                    </script>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```